# Add VERSIONINFO to SFX installer

Tags: powershell, winrar, sfx, versioninfo

I've written a PowerShell script that creates a Self-Extracting Archive (a.k.a. SFX) executable file with [WinRAR command-line](http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/). The problem is that the [VERSIONINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource) metadata is completely empty (accessed by right-clicking the `*.exe` file that was built, going to **Properties**, and clicking on the **Details** tab).

Here is the WinRAR command I'm using in my script:

```bsh
$WinRarInstallPath = "$Env:ProgramFiles\WinRAR\winrar"

<#
    WinRAR arguments used:
        a       - Add files to an archive
        -cfg-   - Ignore default profile and environment variable 
        -ep1    - Exclude base folder from names
        -iadm   - Request administrative access for SFX archive
        -iicon  - Path to icon to use for installer
        -r      - Recurse subfolders
        -sfx    - Create self-extracting archive
        -z      - Path to archive comment file (SFX configuration file)
#>
&$WinRarInstallPath a -cfg- -ep1 -iadm -iicon"$IconPath" -r -sfx -z"$ConfigFilePath" `
    "$InstallerName" "$SourceFilesPath\*" | Out-Null
```

Is there a command-line switch for WinRAR that can allow me to fill in the version and copyright information? If not, is there some way to fill that information in after the SFX's `*.exe` file is built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by manually adding the VERSIONINFO file to a copy of WinRAR's `Default64.SFX` file (found in WinRAR's installation path) and then using that to build the SFX. Here are the steps:

1. Copy the `Default64.SFX` file to somewhere on your hard drive (like your Desktop).
2. Rename the `Default64.SFX` file that you copied in **step 1** to `Default64.exe`.
3. Open `Default64.exe` in Visual Studio (You may need to open Visual Studio, select **File -> Open -> File**, then click the **arrow** on the right side of the **Open** button and click on **Open With...**. Then in the **Open With** dialog that opens, select **Resource Editor** and click the **OK** button).
4. If there is no **Version** folder, right click the top-level folder (named `Default64.exe`) and click on **Add Resource**. Select **Version** in the list and click the **New** button. If there was a **Version** folder, simply double-click the file in the folder.
5. Change all the metadata you need to and save everything.
6. Close Visual Studio.
7. Rename `Default64.exe` back to `Default64.SFX`.
8. Change the PowerShell call to WinRAR's command-line executable and, in the `-sfx` switch, specify the path to the `Default64.SFX` file you modified:

```bsh
&$WinRarInstallPath a -cfg- -ep1 -iadm -iicon"$IconPath" -r -sfx"C:\path\to\Default64.SFX" ` 
    -z"$ConfigFilePath" "$InstallerName" "$SourceFilesPath\*" | Out-Null
```